# How to integerate client(html,js,css) with node and run in a server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have seen so many examples how node works and how node listens to the request.But I always in a confusion in how can we do a complete application with node at server side and run in a server.

Does anyone guide me how can i do a sample application with a login page (html )authenticates user at serverside(Node.js) and sends a response at client side.A complete flow to do a real time application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to deply ext js app in Node.

1.build your Extjs app using sencha cmd

2. copy the generated folder from build--> Productin folder

3.Paste the copied folder in Node server folder(dbview is my ext js app)
[image]

4. find the screenshot to know the files inside my dbview folder

[image]

5. find my node server code in server.js file

   ```
           var express = require('express')
       var app = express()

       app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"\\dbview\\index.html");
       })
       app.use(express.static(__dirname+"\\dbview"));
       var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

         var host = server.address().address
         var port = server.address().port

         console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

       })
   ```

After running my node server file using command node server.js,I am able to access my Application using http://localhost:3000/

Comment: how is this a correct answer to such a generic question?

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html. This will generate a simple, fully working Node.JS Express application in an instant. Reading through this code will help you understand the basics of creating a web app with Node.